# RAWINPUT - How to get Mouse Wheel data

Tags: c++, winapi, directx, raw-input

I'm using rawinput with directx...i'm trying to zoom with the camera when mouse wheel is used...when I run the program with the following code, the data I get from rawinput for the usbuttondata goes to 120 when I push mouse wheel forward...then it goes out of control...up to 65000...I thought the data was supposed to be 1 or -1 or 0...what does rawinput send as the mouse wheel data?

code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg,
                             WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(Msg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            {
                RAWINPUTDEVICE Rid[2];
                // Keyboard
                Rid[0].usUsagePage = 1;
                Rid[0].usUsage = 6;
                Rid[0].dwFlags = 0;
                Rid[0].hwndTarget=Inst.Wnd.hWnd;

                // Mouse
                Rid[1].usUsagePage = 1;
                Rid[1].usUsage = 2;
                Rid[1].dwFlags = 0;
                Rid[1].hwndTarget=Inst.Wnd.hWnd;
                if (!RegisterRawInputDevices(Rid,2,sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICE)))
                {
                    MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed to Register Input Devices!", L"ALERT", MB_OK);
                    exit(1);
                }
                return 0;
            }
        case WM_INPUT:
            {               
                // Determine how big the buffer should be
                UINT iBuffer;

                GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)lParam, RID_INPUT, NULL, &iBuffer,
                    sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));
                LPBYTE lpb = new BYTE[iBuffer];
                if (lpb == NULL)
                {
                    return 0;
                } 

                UINT readSize = GetRawInputData( (HRAWINPUT)lParam, RID_INPUT, lpb, &iBuffer, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER) ) ;

                if( readSize != iBuffer )
                    puts( "ERROR:  GetRawInputData didn't return correct size!" ) ;
                RAWINPUT *raw = (RAWINPUT*) lpb;                

                if (raw->header.dwType== RIM_TYPEMOUSE)
                {
                    riProcessMouseMessage(&raw->data.mouse);
                }
                if (raw->header.dwType== RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD)
                {
                    //riProcessKeyboardMessage(&raw->data.keyboard);
                }               
            }
            return 0;

        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch(LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                case IDM_FILE_NEW:
                {
                    // Create the game object
                    pGame = new CGame(dxMgr.getD3DDevice());

                    // Initialize the game object
                    if (!pGame->init(Inst.Wnd.hWnd))
                        return 0;
                    break;
                }
                case IDM_FILE_OPEN:
                    pGame->m_animCollection->LoadXFile("oxana.x", 0);
                    //objects.CreateNewObject(1, L"oxana.x", NULL);
                    break;

                case IDM_FILE_SAVE:

                    break;

                case IDM_FILE_SAVEAS:
                    break;

                case IDM_FILE_EXIT:
                    PostQuitMessage(WM_QUIT);
                    break;
            }
            return 0;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(WM_QUIT);
            return 0;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return TRUE;
}

void riProcessMouseMessage( const RAWMOUSE* rmouse )
{
    if(pGame != NULL)
    {
        //MessageBox(NULL, L"Game Found", L"SUCCESS", MB_OK);
        if ( MOUSE_MOVE_RELATIVE == rmouse->usFlags )   
        {
            riMgr.mxr = &rmouse->lLastX;        
            riMgr.myr = &rmouse->lLastY;    
        }
        riMgr.mzr = (RI_MOUSE_WHEEL & rmouse->usButtonFlags) ? &rmouse->usButtonData : 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I suspect it is the same as WM_MOUSEWHEEL:

The high-order word indicates the distance the wheel is rotated, expressed in multiples or divisions of WHEEL_DELTA, which is 120. A positive value indicates that the wheel was rotated forward, away from the user; a negative value indicates that the wheel was rotated backward, toward the user.
The low-order word indicates whether various virtual keys are down.

Therefore you need to extract the high order word. You need to take care to handle negative values correctly. You probably don't as you get large values instead.

If you want you can use the following macro for this: GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM(wParam)

Comment: Oh, but then you should cast it to short (signed) to deal with negative values.

Comment: thanks but that didn't work...the mouse wheel data comes from a struct: RAWMOUSE. This data is of type USHORT not WPARAM...the implementation of the struct is like so: RAWMOUSE *raw; USHORT mouseZ = raw->usButtonData; Also, there are no negative numbers...when I scroll mouse wheel forward(away from user) the value is 120 and slowly rises...when I scroll mouse backward(toward user) the value is 65,416 and slowly decreases...this seems illogical and must bew due to incorrect casting of data somewhere right?

Comment: Yes, if you do ((short)(unsigned short)65416) the result is negative (-120). This is what you need to do. Makes more sense?

Comment: Great! If this answers your question - do you need me to edit my original answer for you to accept?

Comment: Similar to OP - I get results of +120 or -120 - but this macro converts those into ... 0. The +/-120 were correct directionally, but lacked magnitude. Is there some extra subtlety with this macro that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in the switch statment

```
case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
{  
    int delta = GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM(wparam);
    if(delta > 0)
    {
        //Mouse Wheel Up
    }
    else
    {
        //Mouse Wheel Down
    }

    return 0;
}
```