# Mouse wheel up and down scroll

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to get mouse wheel up / down scroll events.

I got this so far:

```
switch (uMsg)
{
case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
    if (wParam < 0)
    {
        g_pMenu->SelectedOption--;
    }
    else
    {
        g_pMenu->SelectedOption++;
    }
    break;
}
```

but this does the same thing when I scroll up and down. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Answer in the following link
Visit https://stackoverflow.com/a/63820389/10211028

Answer (score -2):

Solved it. Working code:

```
switch (uMsg)
{
case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
    if ((short)HIWORD(wParam) < 0)
    {
        g_pMenu->SelectedOption--;
    }
    else
    {
        g_pMenu->SelectedOption++;
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: This is not correct. If a user sets their mouse wheel to require a significant amount of rotation to count as one unit of scrolling, this code rejects that and then the user will not be able to scroll your menu because it will scroll too fast. Nor does this fully understand why exactly your original code did not work. I suggest reading [this page](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030807-00/?p=42963/), which talks about how to handle the scroll wheel correctly.